# convert a string to a date inside of a data object

Tags: javascript

I have a data object that looks like this:

```
 costByLob:

 [
    {"key":"Retail","values":[
        {"key":"2015-05","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-06","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-07","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-08","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-09","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-10","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-11","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-12","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-01","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-02","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-03","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-04","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-05","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-06","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-07","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-08","values":1},
        ]
    }
 ]
```

and I'm trying to convert the `"key"` from a `YYYY-MM` to the numerical date version by using `new date()`.

I could loop through the entire object and then put it back together, but is there an easier way to do it then looping through it?

Comment: something has to to a loop somewhere.  `Array.prototype.map` would probably be the best tool in this case.

Comment: 1. Use split function to get month and year. 2. new Date(year,month,date,0,0,0,0)

Comment: you can loop and use moment js library to parse the date it can save you a lot of time (http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, you will have to loop in some fashion. However, the Array.prototype.map function can make your code more concise:

```js
costByLob = [
    {"key":"Retail","values":[
        {"key":"2015-05","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-06","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-07","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-08","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-09","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-10","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-11","values":1},
        {"key":"2015-12","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-01","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-02","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-03","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-04","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-05","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-06","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-07","values":1},
        {"key":"2016-08","values":1},
        ]
    }
 ];
     
costByLob[0]["values"].map(function(data){
     data["key"] = new Date(data["key"]).getTime();
     return data;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(costByLob, '', 2))
```

Comment: seemed to work but w/ another `key` array, it just seems to do the 1st one...`[
 {"key":"Tech","values":
  [
  {"key":1414800000000,"values":1438},
  {"key":1417392000000,"values":1465},
  {"key":1420070400000,"values":2930},
  {"key":1422748800000,"values":293},
  {"key":1425168000000,"values":2930}
  ]
 },
 {"key":"Services","values":
  [
  {"key":"2015-10","values":510},
  {"key":"2015-11","values":831},
  {"key":"2015-12","values":13408},
  {"key":"2016-01","values":16651},
  {"key":"2016-02","values":1732}
  ]
 }
]`

Comment: "It just seems to do the first one."  Yeah, that's what `costByLob[0]` means.  The zero is the first index of the array. You'll have to handle the data as best as you see fit, I'm not going to write example code for all possible variations of your data.